# como puedo hacer que no me muestre todos los registros de varias categorías, solo muestre algunas como referencia

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tardes o días  ocupo una ayuda para hacer este problema que tengo para unas practicas, estoy usando php con laravel y soy nuevo con el tema de laravel , el caso que nose puede estar mi error que muestra todos los registros y lo manda a mi índex principal y solo ocupo que almenos muestre como mínimo los registro de una categoría como referencia para que no se vea saturado y de igual forma me manda doble registro de una categoría cuando recargo la pagina , espero que me ayuden con eso gracias. ese es mi código principal soy nuevo en este lugar y disculpas que nose como funciona esto

```
public function showNewIndex(Request $request) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ip = $request->ip();
    //$data = \Location::get($ip);
    //print_r($data);exit();
    $response = [];
    $favorites = null;
    $country = $request->country == null ? 'US' : $request->country;
    

    if(!Auth::guard('user_login')->guest()) {
        $user = UsersModel::getUsuarioLogueado();
        $favorites = PackageFavoritesModel::where('id_user', $user->id)->get();
    }
    
    $categories = CategoriesModel::where([['active', true], ['is_main', true]])->orderBy('name')->get();
    $categories_not_main = CategoriesModel::where([['active', true], ['is_main', false]])->orderBy('name')->get();
    //$flights = FlightsModel::where('active', true)->orderByDesc('created_at')->limit(8)->get();
    $flights = FlightsModel::select('flights.*')
    ->join('packages_products', 'flights.id', '=', 'packages_products.id_flights')                                    
    ->where([
        ['flights.active', true],
        ['packages_products.active', true],
        ['packages_products.package_type', 'FLY']
    ]) 
    ->orderBy('packages_products.cost', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('flights.created_at', 'asc')->limit(5)->get();


    $flights_pay = FlightsModel::where([['active', true], ['is_pay', 1]])->get();
    $subcategories = SubcategoriesModel::where([['active', true], ['is_visible', true]]);
    $subcats = SubcategoriesModel::where('active', true);
    $categories_all = CategoriesModel::where('active', true)->orderBy('name')
                                     ->union($subcategories)->get();
    $main_gliders = FlightsModel::where([['active', true], ['is_pay', 1]])->groupBy('id_freelancer')->get();
    $page = 'index';
    
    foreach ( $flights as $key => &$flight ) {
        $flight->orderInfo = '';
        $orderCostInfo = $flight->getByOrderCost();
        $getTypeF = $flight->getTypeVuelo();
        $flight->orderInfo = $orderCostInfo->first();
        $flight->getType = $getTypeF->first();
        $flight->name = substr($flight->name, 0, 45);
        
        if ( $flight->orderInfo == '' || ($flight->orderInfo != '' && sizeof($flight->orderInfo->getPictures()) == 0) ) {
            unset($flights[$key]);
        }
    }
    
    $response = [
        'bodyClass' => 'home', 
        'flights' => $flights,
        'categories' => $categories,
        'categories_not_main' => $categories_not_main,
        'categories_all' => $categories_all,
        'subcats' => $subcats,
        'flights_pay' => $flights_pay,
        'favorites' => $favorites,
        'main_gliders' => $main_gliders,
        'page' => $page,
        'country' => $country
    ];
    return view('cliente.newindex',$response);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!